# Put tests into a separate project

Tags: scala, sbt

There are several projects on github that have tests in a separate project, like [Akka](https://github.com/akka/akka) and [Spray](https://github.com/spray/spray). I wonder what are the pros and cons of this approach?

Comment: Usually the reason of putting tests separately is macroses, as they need separate compilation berofre testing